# Why Jacobi symbol allows only odd positive integer in it's denominator?

Tags: cryptography

While referring to the book Cryptography: Theory and Practice by Douglas Stinson, on Page 181 Definition 5.4 (Jacobi Symbol) it was defined that the Jacobi Symbol (a/n) is defined for "n" being a positive odd integer

Now I don't understand what is the need here for "n" to be odd, as why can't we work with even values of "n" in the Jacobi Symbol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: That is why I have added the Tag of "Cryptography"